# Get process information (the command, etc) from pid

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, job-control

I have this code:

```
     for job in `jobs -p`; do
         code=0;
         wait ${job} || code=$?
         if [[ "${code}" != "0" ]]; then
            echo "At least one job failed with exit code => ${code}" ;
            exit 1;
         fi
     done
```

right after the line:
        echo "At least one job failed with exit code => ${CODE}" ;

I want to add a line that logs the command that failed, something like this:

```
     for job in `jobs -p`; do
         code=0;
         wait ${job} || code=$?
         if [[ "${code}" != "0" ]]; then
            echo "At least one job failed with exit code => ${code}" ;
            echo "The job that failed was $(ps -p ${job})"
            exit 1;
         fi
     done
```

not that a `job` is just the pid of the subprocess. The problem is that this line:

```
echo "The job that failed was $(ps -p ${job})"
```

doesn't really about anything - I need the actually command that was run, given the pid=job.

Answer (score 3):

At the point you're running the `ps` command, the process already exited (you're handling its return code, right?)

Just change the logic so you run the `ps` command earlier in the script, before the `wait` and store that in a variable:

```
for job in $(jobs -p); do
    process_info=$(ps -p "${job}" -o args=)
    wait "${job}" || {
        code=$?
        echo "Job running [${process_info}] failed with exit code ${code}." >&2
        exit 1
    }
done
```

Comment: thanks, seems like the right idea, but not sure if this works on MacOS though, got something x-platform?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't...

Comment: take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/2f0444cadef5b3546fca0eec749b4b70

Comment: I just get a blank line => $process_info is just empty...I tried a lot of things...nothing is working :(

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger You can't do this either in case the jobs exit out of order. For example, if the last job in the output of `jobs -p` exits first.

Comment: Ignoring the timing issues, `ps -p PID -o args=` works in macOS (just try it directly in Terminal with the PID of a running process)

Answer (score 0):

[As pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433210/116858), you can't use `ps` on a non-existing process.

If you have a `bash` that supports associative arrays:

```
declare -A jobinfo

# collect job information
joblist=( $(jobs -p) )
for pid in "${joblist[@]}"; do
    jobinfo["$pid"]="$( ps -p "$pid" -o args= )"
done

# later...

# wait for jobs
err=0
for pid in "${joblist[@]}"; do
    if ! { wait "$pid" || ! (( code=$? )); }; then
        printf 'Got non-zero exit status (%d) from PID %d: %s\n' \
            "$code" "$pid" "${jobinfo[$pid]}"
        err=1
    fi
done

# exit 0 if all was good, exit 1 otherwise
exit "$err"
```

Here I collect all the necessary data before starting to wait for jobs to exit.  I also wait for *all* jobs to finish so that the user gets information about not just the first failing job.

---

Without using associative arrays (should work in the default `bash` on macOS):

```
# collect job information
joblist=( $(jobs -p) )
for pid in "${joblist[@]}"; do
    jobinfo+=( "$( ps -p "$pid" -o args= )" )
done

# later...

err=0
i=0
for pid in "${joblist[@]}"; do
    if ! { wait "$pid" || ! (( code=$? )); }; then
        printf 'Got non-zero exit status (%d) from PID %d: %s\n' \
            "$code" "$pid" "${jobinfo[$i]}"
        err=1
    fi

    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

exit "$err"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your OS (e.g. Linux) has a /proc directory, you can get every needed information from /proc/$PID

```
for PID in $(jobs -p); do
    dosomethingwith /proc/$PID/ # please take a look at what it contents ;-)
    done
```